# Is Overriding part of abstraction?

Tags: java, android, object

When I override the OnCreate method in Android Development (or any method) am I making use of abstraction here? What I mean is, has the method I am overridng been marked as Abstract?

Comment: No you are not. Activity is a concrete class

Comment: read the doc, it is written there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the documentation of a single well-identified method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No a method is only abstract if it has the abstract modifier.  It can only be abstract if it has no body.  Overriding a method will not make it abstract, it simply covers it up.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not.

Strictly abstract methods are not defined, but need to be in child classes.

When you override a method, you can still call it on super, so it exists (being not strictly abstract).